# Driver for RAID-0 TRIM passthrough on AMD southbridge

Tags: drivers, raid-0, trim

**Intel** provides a driver that enables **RAID-0 TRIM passthrough** for Intel 7 Series chipsets:

http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=21407

Do you know where **AMD** provides their driver to enable **RAID-0 TRIM passthrough** for **AMD SB700-series southbridges**?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, AMD doesn't provide such functionality (especially for the SB700).